# angular matSelect with suffix trigger click on clear

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to add a simple icon on the right of my input in order to clear his content.

I don't want to add a "none" option in my list.

I want to add a "clear" button.

Actually, everything is ok but when I click on the clear button the select is displaying ...

here's a test code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mpbl8q

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>State</mat-label>
  <mat-select [(ngModel)]="currentState" name="State">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="state">{{state}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
  <div matSuffix>
    <mat-icon (click)="currentState = null">clear</mat-icon>
  </div>
</mat-form-field>
```

The click on clear is opening the mat-select

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You must add $event.stopPropagation() in the click action.

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nmbxgn